# How to add color and change space between ticks in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I am currently learning r, I try to produce a time series graph with `ggplot()`, here is my current code:

```
library(readxl)
library(ggplot2)

AUS_GDP <- c(826, 834, 858, 886, 936, 982, 999, 1030, 1057, 1114, 1352, 
1398, 1428, 1435, 1508, 1825, 1793, 1881, 1857, 1733, 2190, 1868, 
1704, 1975, 2246, 2310, 2554, 2954, 3381, 3339, 3148, 3736, 4382, 
4798, 4202, 3988, 4866, 4294, 3661, 4728, 4613, 4544, 4368, 4352, 
4616, 4403, 4532, 4956, 5031, 4932, 5217, 5259, 5663, 6095, 6113, 
6596, 6387, 6433, 6817, 6703, 6830, 7101, 6476, 7133, 6861, 7049, 
6900, 7383, 7179, 7567, 7106, 7438, 6368, 5910, 6003, 5558, 5874, 
5451, 6202, 6121, 6397, 6119, 6094, 6497, 6846, 6825, 7184, 7358, 
7481, 7940, 8305, 8136, 8126, 8220, 8013, 7806, 7775, 7637, 7336, 
7517, 7597, 7828, 8072, 8276, 8635, 8851, 8883, 8837, 8690, 8389, 
7504, 6940, 7275, 7718, 8066, 8477, 8792, 9159, 9382, 9318, 9828, 
10820, 11963, 12278, 11735, 11026, 10512, 10622, 11105, 11536, 
11815, 11966, 11824, 11963, 12419, 12795, 12924, 12895, 13238, 
13753, 14013, 13793, 14389, 14983, 15699, 16182, 16324, 17108, 
17770, 18428, 19166, 19590, 19772, 20527, 20698, 20993, 21613, 
21592, 21948, 22826, 22972, 23368, 22972, 22697, 24009, 24927, 
25116, 25971, 26702, 27407, 27373, 26861.2749592856, 27560.1782773384, 
28622.4757584582, 29844.1713244349, 30690.0624398521, 31740.4697474047, 
32857.9937806025, 34337.139432097, 35551.0195059737, 36603.0449959447, 
37275.9912489095, 38567.0654883377, 39523.6551974459, 40887.725336397, 
41904.4458707113, 42650.9859308496, 44033.5837617713, 44421.6404707281, 
44686.541383463, 45400.2233987967, 46132, 46999, 47250, 47867, 
48357, 48845, 49265.6135020065, 49830.7993065638)
log_AUS_GDP <- log(AUS_GDP)
year <- 1820:2018
AUS <- data.frame(year = year, 
                  gdp = AUS_GDP,
                  log_gdp = log_AUS_GDP)


ggplot(AUS, aes(x = year, y = gdp)) +
  geom_line() + 
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(angle = 90, vjust = 0.1, size = 10)) +
  scale_x_continuous("year", labels = as.character(year), breaks = year)
```

And here is what I have right now:
[image]

I wish to achieve something like this；
[image]

but I am not sure how to do that, can someone show me the way? Thank you so much!

Comment: I'm going to go out on a limb and say that your x-axis column is `"character"`, is that right? Even if it *looks* like a date or such, but if `class(AUS$year)` returns `"character"`, it will be interpreted as a categorical variable and really clutter axis ticks/labels. Please provide the output from `dput(head(AUS))`. Thanks!

Comment: Further, to get multiple lines, you need to have a column indicating (for instance) Country. That would likely be done with `aes(year, gdp, color = country)`.

Comment: yes, the x-axis was indeed created by scale_x_continuous("year", labels = as.character(year), breaks = year), how should I change that to make it more pretty?

Comment: Ahh ... well, with `breaks=year`, you're telling it to display *every* ... *single* ... *year*, which is not what you have in your desired output. But now I'm confused ... that's a ggplot scaling function that you did not include in your code, so ... are you using that, and gave us only a portion of your plotting code?

Comment: oh sorry, didn't realize i missed a line, just editted

Comment: That's better. Please, though, sample data? BTW: please do not add [tag:rstudio], this question is about [tag:r] and [tag:ggplot2], not about anything else you have there. ([tag:plot] is perhaps okay, but within [tag:r] it typically means base-R plotting, not `ggplot2`-based code.)

Comment: got it, here is the data, just editted

Comment: I have no idea how to use that data, it doesn't even appear columnar. *Please* use `dput` to provide sample data, it is unambiguous (in contrast to most other methods) and the simplest for others to use quickly.

Comment: Got it, just edited, thank you!

Comment: ***Please***. If I try to use that *vector* instead of a `data.frame`, then I try `ggplot(AUS, aes(x = year, y = gdp))`. This yields `Error: \`data\` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by \`fortify()\`, not a numeric vector`, which is no surprise (to me, at least), since `ggplot` (just as you are using it) requires a frame as its `data=` argument. If you want help getting *that* frame with `year` and `gdp` to plot and add colors by something (e.g., `country`), then you need to provide sample data that includes all of those components.

Comment: just editted, i believe this time will do, thank you!

Comment: Perhaps it would be easier to start with a known dataset like the 'gapminder' dataset, e.g. see this tutorial: https://rafalab.github.io/dsbook/gapminder.html#time-series-plots

Comment: MichaelZhang, that's more usable, thank you. Two things: (1) you ask for color, and the expected graphic shows different countries, but your data doesn't support that, how do you intended to vary color? (2) Your expected output shows ticks every four years, is that what you're after? The `breaks=year` defies that ...

Answer (score 0):

I think you have different dataframes for each country. You can combine them in one dataframe with a `country` column that identifies each dataset and plot them with `ggplot`.

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

bind_rows(lst(AUS, US, FRANCE), .id = 'country') %>%
  ggplot(aes(year, gdp, color = country)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  labs(x = 'YEAR', 
       y = 'GDP', 
       title = 'GDP per Capita in France, UK and the US')
```

Answer (score 0):

Keep it simple: like below:
I added one column with `Country` Aus

```
ggplot(AUS, aes(x = year, y = gdp, color=Country)) +
  geom_line() +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(legend.position="bottom")
```

[image]